# Зашифровать параметры url в хэш с возможностью декодировать

Tags: javascript

Привет. У меня в проекте на одной из страниц генерируется длинная url в адресной строке с десятком параметров. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы эти параметры хэшировались(с целью уменьшения длинны url и создания permalink и доступа к нему в дальнейшем). Например, пользователь переходит по ссылке

> example.com/?foo=bar&baz=foo&date=18:02:01-2017-07-04

Но, чтобы вместо ссылки у него был, например, хэш в MD5

> example.com?requestid=06ad47d8e64bd28de537b62ff85357c4

И когда пользователь через некоторое время возвращался на страницу с этим параметром, то чтобы он снова расшифровывался в `?foo=bar` и так далее. Как это можно реализовать и можно ли для этого использовать MD5?

Comment: хэш нельзя расшифровать, он потому и хэш

Comment: Нельзя. Хэширование - это не шифрование

Comment: Храните таблицу (один requestid - набор параметров). Но только не хэш (он не гарантирует уникальности) - для этих целей вполне подойдёт рандомный набор символов, проверенный на уникальность.

Comment: @Akina какие для этого есть инструменты?

Comment: Инструменты - для чего? для создания таблиц? для генерации рандомных строк? для проверки на уникальность? Только не говорите, что у Вас в комплекте ПО сайта нет базы данных...

Comment: @Akina нет базы данных. По этому и интересуюсь :) Для начала подскажите, какие инструменты можно использовать для генерации рандомных и в то же время уникальных строк.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, на уникальность можно проверить только отправляя запрос в PHP, где тот будет сравнивать с базой данных

Comment: *нет базы данных* - но хранить где-то придётся. Не забивать же память веб-сервера? И хранить долго, в т.ч. и при рестартах - ведь человек по этой ссылке может и через месяц попытаться пройти... Если не будет БД, то придётся извращаться с другими форматами хранения (CSV, XML, JSON и т.п. в plain text или около того), хранилище будет постоянно пухнуть, а время записи, проверки, поиска - расти. Так что заведите себе какую-никакую БД, и проблема почти исчезнет.

Comment: @Akina что можете посоветовать? Какую именно БД? В моём частном случае БД нужна лишь для сбора статистики и складирования описанных в задаче данных.

Comment: Если есть free БД, которую Вы хорошо знаете - её. Если нет - ту, что лучше всего подходит к программной (скриптовой) "части" ПО сайта.

Comment: @Akina у меня JS и PHP.

Comment: *у меня JS* - на сервере? *и PHP* - PHP прекрасно себя мироощущает, работая со многими СУБД (см. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.drivers.php), но наиболее облизанная из них (по которой больше всего примеров и готовых решений) - MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Хэш нельзя расшифровать.

Есть пару вариантов, как решить ваш вопрос:

1. Создать в БД таблицу, где будет храниться хэш, или рандомный набор символов, и параметры, которые он несёт.
2. Шифровать с помощью других методов, которые можно расшифровывать

   К примеру:

   ```js
   function сaesar(text, key, decode) {
     var textLetter, keyLetter, result = "",
       conv = decode ? -1 : 1;
     key = key ? key : " ";
     for (textLetter = keyLetter = 0; textLetter < text.length; textLetter++, keyLetter++) {
       if (keyLetter >= key.length) keyLetter = 0;
       result += String.fromCharCode(text.charCodeAt(textLetter) + conv * key.charCodeAt(keyLetter));

     }
     return result
   }
   $(function() {
     $('[value="Шифровать"]').click(function() {
       var text = prompt('Вставьте ваш текст для шифрования:', '');
       if (text != '') {
         var val;
         for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
           val += '%' + text.charCodeAt(i);
         }
         prompt('Зашифрованный текст:', сaesar(val.replace(/^undefined/, ''), '0135'))
       }
     })
     $('[value="Расшифровать"]').click(function() {
       var text = сaesar(prompt('Вставьте ваш текст для расшифрования:', ''), 0, true);
       if (text != '') {
         var arr = JSON.parse('[' + text.replace(/\%/g, ',').replace(/^\,(.+)/, '$1') + ']');
         var val;
         for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           val += String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
         }
         prompt('Расшифрованный текст:', val.replace(/^undefined/, ''))
       }
     })
   })
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <input type="button" value="Шифровать">
   <input type="button" value="Расшифровать">
   ```